# How to calculate the overlap of four cartesian gaussian function i.e $\int \phi_{A}(r)\phi_{B}(r)\phi_{C}(r)\phi_{D}(r)d^{3}r$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I want to calculate
$\int \phi_{A}(r)\phi_{B}(r)\phi_{C}(r)\phi_{D}(r)d^{3}r$ where
$\phi_{A}(r)=(x-A_{x})^{l1}(y-A_{y})^{l2}(z-A_{z})^{l3}e^{-\alpha |r-A|^{2}}$. l1, l2 and l3 are integers Can you suggest any book and any code in c++/matlab that can calculate this quantity?

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please note that these are not Gaussians. Also, I don't see the direct connection to physics.

Comment: If you want or need to do it numerically, why can’t you use [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html)?

Comment: It should be doable analytically in spherical coordinates, but expanding it will produce a large number of terms.